# Save Text View as an image file

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, android-image

My application has a textview and an ImageView , I want to save both as a single Image file to the device storage

My layouts :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/second_splash" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Top Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textSize="35sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:shadowColor="@color/butbg"
android:shadowRadius="20"
/>
```

How can I perform this efficiently ?

Comment: Save as Image file! Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot programatically a save it. In order to do this have a look here : [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)